# Add your application to a Docker image

Tags: macos, docker, clang, dockerfile, docker-image

I am implementing a docker container to compile (build) my code which is in C++. Platforms supported by my code are Windows, Linux and Mac OSX.

I am using clang on my Mac machine to compile the code; gcc on Linux and Microsoft compiler(cl) on Windows. The idea is to create a Docker container and perform the builds(of both Linux and Mac) on Windows machine itself (inside a docker container) so that I don't have to push the code to git; then pull it from my Mac machine and then build and so on.

The image I am using to perform Mac build (since I am using clang on Mac OSX) is https://hub.docker.com/r/rsmmr/clang/.

I want to add an executable to this image which is for testing purpose. It is called 'testapp'.

So the image should have following components:
Base OS + Clang + testapp.

How can I add my executable 'testapp' (say: application/utlity) to this image 'rsmmr/clang'(which I pulled from dockerhub) ?

Do I do this via Dockerfile (how?)?
Is there any other way to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple way to solve this is my mounting your source/binary testapp to the `clang` image.

To demonstrate this, I created a testapp.cc myself and it looked like this:

```
[anovil@ubuntu-anovil add_application_docker_image]$ cat testapp.cc 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
[anovil@ubuntu-anovil add_application_docker_image]$
```

Then, launched the `rsmmr/clang` container by passing my local directory to the container plus running the compilation command like this:

```
[anovil@ubuntu-anovil add_application_docker_image]$ docker run -v $(pwd):/mnt -it rsmmr/clang /opt/llvm/bin/clang++ --std=c++11 --stdlib=libc++ /mnt/testapp.cc -o /mnt/a.out
[anovil@ubuntu-anovil add_application_docker_image]$
```

After this, the `a.out` will be in your local directory (as it was mounted to the container).

```
[anovil@ubuntu-anovil add_application_docker_image]$ ls
a.out  testapp.cc
[anovil@ubuntu-anovil add_application_docker_image]$
```

If you want to execute that binary inside the container, you can do this as well.

```
[anovil@ubuntu-anovil add_application_docker_image]$ docker run -v $(pwd):/mnt -it rsmmr/clang /mnt/a.out
Hello World!
[anovil@ubuntu-anovil add_application_docker_image]$
```

You could do the similar things with other compilers as well. I do not have a windows machine, but it should work :)
Was something like this you wanted?

Let me know how it went.

Thanks,

- Anoop

Comment: Thanks for your inputs :)

Comment: What I want is the 'a.out' to be a part of the image. I have ready made 'a.out'. Now, I want to integrate a.out with this docker image; so that, when I take this image to a different machine and run this image to create a container; I have a.out available in this container.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing you can do this by creating your own Dockerfile and make your own image.

Start your Dockerfile with

```
FROM install-clang
```

Then add what you need.

```
COPY a.out directoryinthecontainer/
```

If you need further action to be taken during the creation of the image, use

```
RUN apt-get morepackage && execute mycommand && unpack somefile.tar
```

You get the picture: these can be any operating system commands you like. 
If you want that app to be run as core part of your new image add

```
ENTRYPOINT ["directoryinthecontainer/a.out", "-myoptions"]
```

or

```
CMD ["directoryinthecontainer/a.out", "-myoptions"]
```

There are subtle differences when you would use ENTRYPOINT, RUN or CMD, which would depend on your use case.

See the [Dockerfile Reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) to find out which one may do what you want.

Edit: I thought I'd clarify the next step:

Use your Dockerfile to create your own image with

```
docker build -t myrepo/myimage:mytag .
```

Don't forget that '.' (period) at the end of the command line!

From then on out you can use your own image to create a container that will do everything from the original CLANG one plus your additional features. It's one of my favourite features! :)

Comment: Thanks for your input :). I'll explore further.